# Using a U.S. router with U.S. power supply in India

Tags: power-supply, wireless-router, adapter, international

I took a Belkin Share Max N300 router bought in the USA and connected it directly to power in India. Specifications of the router's power adaptor are input 120V AC 50/60Hz 0.5A, and the output is 12.0V DC 1.5A. How can I make my router work again?

Comment: You don't...you provide a device with to much voltage

Comment: If you're lucky, another (properly rated) power supply will do the trick. If you're unlucky - buy another router.

Comment: That is quite unusual - most of the routers I have used came with switch mode power supplies that work over a range of voltages, from 100 - 240 V and that would have gone meh, and worked. With a fixed voltage device you *should* have used a voltage converter between it and the mains

Answer (score 2):

For starters, try another power supply (230V). 
Maybe you were lucky and only the power supply got bricked and not the device (India=230V).

Answer (score 0):

On the back of your router there will be a power input spec next to the power jack.  Find a new power supply that takes the same connector, has an identical voltage, has a slightly higher or much higher amp rating, and that is rated for the Indian wall power. The good news is that the reason why there are separate power bricks from the main device is for purposes of interoperability in the various countries.